# Unable to use the old .jks key after enrolling to Google Play App Signing

Tags: android

I am getting following error message from Play Store when i try to upload a new APK.

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key before you upload it.

Comment: So did you sign your APK with a new key before you upload it?

Comment: Follow the advice given. This is all intentional. Read the whole thing https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question. Yes you should start using a new Key.

Comment: Yes i did that to avoid the problem.